# How can I add file_handle parameter to call_user_func_ex in php my own extension?

Tags: php, c++, opcache

I would like to use my own function in zendaccelerator.c, but I can't pass file_handler parameter to call_user_func_ex. Please check my sample and give me some advice...

```
zend_op_array *own_compile_file(zend_file_handle *file_handle, int type TSRMLS_DC) {
    zval *function_name;
    zend_op_array *opcode_array;
    zval *params = { file_handle, TSRMLS_DC };

    TSRMLS_FETCH();

    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(function_name);
    ZVAL_STRINGL(function_name, FUNC_NAME, strlen(FUNC_NAME));

    if (call_user_function_ex(CG(function_table), NULL, function_name,       &opcode_array, 2, params, 0, NULL TSRMLS_CC) != SUCCESS) {
        zend_error(E_ERROR, "Function name compile failed");

        return NULL;
    }

    FREE_ZVAL(function_name);

    return opcode_array;
}
```

When I do make on Centos7, I get this error message:
Warning: Initialization from incompatible pointer type (zval *params...)